# MySQL castr operator

Tags: mysql, casting

Is there any shorter equivalent for the following query: (I can not alter the table). Are cast operators applicable here?

```
select convert(old_text using utf8) as text,
   convert(rev_timestamp using utf8) as ts,
   convert(rev_user_text using utf8) as user from revision;
```

Update: The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE `revision` (
    `rev_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rev_page` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `rev_text_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `rev_comment` TINYBLOB NOT NULL,
    `rev_user` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `rev_user_text` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `rev_timestamp` BINARY(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0',
`old_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`old_text` MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
`old_flags` TINYBLOB NOT NULL,
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

the best is to alter your table and set utf8 for your needed columns instead of everytime converting them

```
    ALTER TABLE t MODIFY old_text CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
    ALTER TABLE t MODIFY rev_timestamp CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
    ALTER TABLE t MODIFY rev_user_text CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

and then select them normal.

```
select old_text  as text, rev_timestamp  as ts, rev_user_text as user 
from revision;
```

**note:** about char(50) change it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
set names utf8;

SELECT old_text AS text, rev_timestamp AS ts, rev_user_text AS user
FROM revisions;
```

...but this will break if you are sending DML in a different character set.

Comment: "does not work" is not a meaningful descrioption of happenned, nor is it an error message.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to modify, is to modify the my.ini file in mysql character set key,

```
default-character-set = utf8 
character_set_server = utf8
```

After modification, restart the mysql service, service mysql restart

Comment: Wrong. This won't convert anything. Newly inserted data will be ut8 yes, but nothing else.